# How to get the modulus of a number in XPath/XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xpath, modulo

I want to calculate the modulus of a number in the XPath, but this is not working:

```
<xsl:if test="(count()%8)">
```

How would I do it? I Looked at the XPath [function reference here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp), but didn't see anything like that.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

try "mod"

see http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#numbers

Details from that link:

> The mod operator returns the remainder from a truncating division. For
>   example,
>
> 5 mod 2 returns 1
>
> 5 mod -2 returns 1
>
> -5 mod 2 returns -1
>
> -5 mod -2 returns -1
>
> NOTE: This is the same as the % operator in Java and ECMAScript.

Answer (score 18):

Try

```
<xsl:if test="(count() mod 8)">
```

as in XSL you have to use "mod" to get modulus

Answer (score 6):

Also watch out when doing addition/subtraction.  When doing addition all should be good with $var1+$var2.  But in Subtraction, since a dash (-) is valid in a variable name $var1-$var2 does not work.  But $var1 - $var2 should, and number($var1) - number($var2) always should work and you can see an article I wrote about in relation to the use of XPATH in Novell's Identity Manager product.

[XPATH Math thoughts](http://www.novell.com/communities/node/6109/xpath-and-math)